# Dynamic creation of tables (classes) with DataMapper?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

So, i'm trying to make a small "social network" for educational purposes but i'm stuck at giving the users "friends" in the database. You can probably do it in a easier way but the only way that I could think of was to have a separate table for each user that contains their friends.

However, to do this, I need to create tables dynamically with a variable as table name. I've tried with const_set but it seems like it doesn't work with DataMapper for some reason (or I might just be stupid). Keep getting errors like `uninitialized constant Serial` when I'm trying to add properties.

So what should I do? Is there a solution? Can I create tables dynamically some other way? Or is there an easier way of saving the friends.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need multiple tables for this?

Comment: Managed to come up with a solution. Still curious of how to do this though. It might come in handy.

Comment: It would be good for you to answer your own question, and then give that answer the checkmark to indicate that it is a working solution.  Others having the same question as you will be glad to know what the solution is.

Comment: The thing is that I haven't found an answer to my question, I have only found another solution to my problem. I'm still curious of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
module DMSerial
  def self.included base
    base.class_eval do
      include DataMapper::Resource
      property :id,           base::Serial
    end
  end
end

def create_model model_name, &block
  Object.const_set(model_name, Class.new)
  model = Object.const_get(model_name)
  model.class_eval {include DMSerial}
  model.class_eval &block
end

[1,2,3].each do |num|

  create_model "Model#{num}" do
    property :val,  Integer, :default => num
  end

end
```